# How to add a project as a reference of another project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, reference

I'm trying to add a project that contains some classes as a reference to another project, but I have not got, all your suggestions will be great

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Add both projects to the same solution.  Then one project can add a "Project Reference" to the other project.

Comment: can you just make it a dll then reference the DLL. If you add one solution 2 projects, then you would have to all the files to your 2nd project which could work, but would have double maintence

Comment: What ? You do not have double maintenance. The project from solution A is referenced into solution B. Maintenance stays the same.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Open the **File** menu.
2. Choose **Add**, then **Existing project**
3. Add the project you want into your solution

s[image]

4. From the **solution explorer**, select the **References** item of the project you want to need to reference the "other project" into.
5. Click on **Add reference**
6. Choose the **project item**
7. Add your other project as reference to the main project.

[image]

Alternatively, you can compile the other project as DLL and add it (as dll) to your main project.

Comment: How should one proceed if the references (like nuget packages) from the project being added as a reference themselves show as broken references in your main project?

Comment: @sergeidave I think what you want to do in this case is to right-click the solution and click on the "Restore nuget packages" element.

Comment: I tried restoring them multiple times but they show up still broken. The thing is that when I open the external projects by themselves with their own sln file, their references show up just fine, but when I open the main sln file, from the solution to which I've added these external projects, their references now show up broken when viewed in the main sln.

Comment: @sergeidave I f you did not already figure it out, you should create a separate question to have more visibility. This is sufficiently different from OP question and unfortunately, I have no clear answer on your specific case myself.