# Developing and debugging projects in mutli-repository in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

This is the basics of the problem I am having (of course it is oversimplified for the sake of the question):
I have 2 projects in a solution stored in mono-repository:

- Project1 - outputs a library
- Project2 - outputs an executable

When Project2 references Project1.

I would like to move to multi-repository where Project1 will be stored in different Repository from Project2.
Project1 will output a nuget package and Project2 will reference it instead the project itself.

The issue I am facing: in current situation (mono-repository) when during development I introduce a feature in
Project2 that also requires a change in Project1 it is not a problem. If there are problems I can discover it
during development time.

In a new way (multi-repository) I first need to make a change to Project1, create nuget and push it to nuget
store, then update reference in Project2. If I would have problems in Project1, I must go back to Project1,
fix the issue and push it again, update reference in Project2 and so on. Also, losing the benefit of debugging
both projects.

Is there a solution to this approach? To focus my question: if I have source codes of both projects on my dev machine,
is it possible somehow to instruct Visual Studio to use source code instead of referenced Nuget for debugging?

Hope I explained it right and clear as possible...

Comment: I don't know if it solves your problem, but it is possible to reference the same projects in another solution. I.e., two different solutions can reference the same projects. You can also link source files of another project in a new project.

Comment: As Olivier said, In visual studio, you can add project reference to another project from another solution by adding existing project to current solution. Then you can take advantage of this feature to debug and pack more easily in current solution. And another good point is though the current solution added the existing project, the structure of the solution where the added project once exists won't be broken. About add project reference to project from other solution see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397568/how-to-add-a-project-as-a-reference-of-another-project).

Comment: Thank you both for answers, but you missed the point of the question. I am looking into turning library project into nuget package but still need a way to be able to debug it during development.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different projects and both of them are in different repositories, you could add the library as a submodule of the first project. I'm assuming you're using git. You could do this simply by:

```
    git submodule add <link for the other repo>
```

In visual studio you just add the project to the same solution and then reference library from the executable. I'm not sure if that would do the trick for you, but I hope that works.

Comment: Thanks, but eventually I would like the project2 to target the Nuget of project 1. But that actually solves another issue I was thinking of related to git.

Answer (score 0):

We have the exact same problem in our company.
This is 2 part problem.
First part is to have both repositories near each other... There are more options, we were deciding between these 2:

- git submodule
- meta repository (it is a compromise between mono-repository and multi-repository) you have 2 repositories you want to connect, so you create 3rd repository as a meta-repository via https://github.com/mateodelnorte/meta

Second part is how to connect those 2 repositories so that they are debuggable, but still apart each other... We though of these 3 ways:

- new .sln in meta repository that will reference both projects (this didn't cut it, because we already been in a position when we had multiple .sln files and maintaining them is not that easy, because when you add some project into one, you have to add it to the other solutions and this goes sideways really quick)
- using Reference and PackageReference with Condition - locally for debugging when .dll is build in ProjA then the ProjB would use "Reference", if not the ProjB would use PackageReference => this was our main solution to our problem until we did it like that... (Because we have more than 2 projects ProjA -> ProjB -> ProjC.. The problem here was when it was built locally, referenced via Reference DLL, then ProjA was not visible from ProjC, but when built via CI and referenced via PackageReference, then ProjA was visible from ProjC)
- using only Nugets - Every build of ProjA it will create nuget locally (pre-release) and in ProjB, we would reference that via wild-cards. This works, until you make a second change into ProjA, because ProjB will cache that nuget in C:/Users//.nuget/packages :( so when building ProjA and packing the nuget we clear the newly built nuget from this packages folder. You have to restore ProjB every time you make change into ProjA, but this is where we landed as a final solution for now.

So the final solution for us is:

- meta-repository for like 5 other repositories
- for debugging we use locally built nugets with constant version of "major.minor.patch.65534-local"
- for CI we use the same nuget packaging but we override the local version with

  - feature branches "major.minor.patch.build_number-branch_name" (having -something after the version makes that nuget pre-release)
  - master/main branch "major.minor.path.build_number"