# Create object from class stored in a DLL

Tags: vb.net, dll, namespaces

Trying to understand namespaces, I added a class *MyUtils* to my solution with the following structure:

```vb
Imports ...

Namespace DButils.AAA

  Public Class BBB

    Public Sub DoSomething()
      ' ...
    End Sub

  End Class

End Namespace
```

I compiled the solution as DLL. Now I want to call Method *DoSomething*. I tried the following code in another application:

```vb
Imports MyUtils

Module NamespaceTest

  Private Sub Test()
    Dim obj As New DButils.AAA.BBB
    obj.DoSomething()
  End Sub

End Module
```

That doesn't work. I tried several other combinations of class, namespace, with and without *Imports*, etc. but can't find a way to call that procedure. I seem to understand something totally wrong here. Any hint?

Comment: Did you reference the dll?

Comment: Wow, that's it. I referenced the dll from the *Release* folder, but I should have used the *Debug* folder. Thanks.

Comment: If both projects are in the same solution you can reference it from the `Projects` tab instead and save you the hassle of changing between referencing the Debug or Release version. Project references are automatically updated to reflect changes in the build configuration.

Comment: Thanks, @VisualVincent. My projects don't belong to the same solution at this point. Maybe I should integrate them into one. Will think about it. Is there a good reason to do so?

Comment: @Anumi you can include the same project in two different solutions. An example would be a class library with extension methods which you want to have access to in multiple solutions. The reason Vincent mentioned is probably the best. When p2 is included in a solution, and referenced by p1, if p1 is built, p2 will also build prior to p1 if there are changes to any file in it.

Comment: In addition you also don't have to open another instance of Visual Studio in order to modify p2. To expand on djv's comment, a project can be included in multiple solutions without having to be copied to each solution's folder (i.e. it only needs to be in one location on disk).

Comment: @djv and VisualVincent: "same project in different solutions" sonds very interisting. Will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Just make sure to make a [project reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37398196/832052) instead of referencing the dll directly