# How to combine multiple sensors into one project with separate drivers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, configuration-files, ximea

I am creating an application that requires a Ximea camera and a sensor which is connected to a driver. Both are C++ compatible. The problem is that the Ximea camera only builds in x86 on Visual Studio and the sensor builds on x64. I would like to run both from the same project, and I believe that I need to use MSBuild or some sort of Batch Build to configure both so that they can both run at the same time. I essentially want to take images from the camera to steer the sensor, so they both need to be running at the same time.

[Here](https://www.ximea.com/support/wiki/apis/xiapi_manual) is a link to the API I am using for the camera.

(This is my first time working heavily in C++ so any advice/references/resources would be great!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to run both from the same project, and I believe that I
>   need to use MSBuild or some sort of Batch Build to configure both so
>   that they can both run at the same time.

Run and build means different things, you can use msbuild or batch scripts to build Ximea camera project in X86 and the sensor project in X64 when you build the whole solution.

In VS you can right-click Solution in Solution Explorer=>Configuration Manager to control this behavior. See:

[image]

Then when you choose Solution Platform x86, it actually builds the project A and B in X64, and C in X86. This is what msbuild can do for you. But I can't make sure if there will be compatibility issue when you run it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am able to put both projects within one solution and build them both soundly. Now that they can both build, I would like to reference the camera in the other / the sensor in the other too but don't quite know how to go about doing that. This is definitely a start though!

Comment: @Ryanator13 Do you mean adding project reference like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37398196/10910450)?