# why do I have to rebuild VB.Net 2015 project every time I make a code change?

Tags: vb.net, debugging, rebuild

Quick question. Working in VB.NET 2015, on a new form I've added to an existing project. Until recently I've never had to recompile (Rebuild) the project in order to have debugging work, always just saved the changes and ran the project no problem.

But with this new form I have to rebuild the project every time I make a change or when I try to debug the breakpoints are all disabled.

I'm sure something isn't right, but I have no clue what to look at. Any ideas? This is a standard forms project, not for the web.

Thanks

Craig

Comment: What method did you use to run the project? If it was F5, then it was doing the build for you but you just didn't notice - perhaps the Output window wasn't visible so you saw no messages about the build process.

Comment: Your project probably has a reference to the compiled DLL, so any changes you make to those classes in the DLL...well the project doesn't know about them until you re-compile it.

Comment: If you don't rebuild the project then your changes in the code _won't_ be reflected in the output assembly (.exe/.dll). When starting the project through Visual Studio (via the "Start debugging" button or F5 on your keyboard) your project is automatically saved and rebuilt before it launches. If you didn't notice the rebuild before but you do so now that means that something has changed, causing the rebuild to go slower than it used to.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have added the source code to your project,
but you still have a reference to the dll on hard disk in your start-project.

There is no dependency, that a change in your project, will have an effect to your startup-application. There is, but Visual Studio doesn't know about it.

You can set the Project Depedencies manually.
But it's better to remove the reference to your "new existing" project, and re-add it as a project - not as a DLL.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37398196/832052) for instructions