# Use dependency from one project to another in the same solution

Tags: c#, reference

Is it a way of using a dependency from a project to another while they are in the same solution? For example:

```
ComputerVisionProject (solution):
    1. ComputerVision.FaceRecognition
    2. ComputerVision.Core
    3 .ComputerVision.UI
```

In the first project: ComputerVision.FaceRecognition, I install a nugget, for example, "OpenCV" and I can use all the functions from it with "using OpenCV", but only in the ComputerVision.FaceRecognition project.
What I want is to use the same functions in the second project, ComputerVision.Core. but I don't want to install again the nugget, and seems that only "using OpenCV" doesn't work (even if I add the entire project as a reference to the second one)  Is it possible to make another type of reference or something like: "using ComputerVision.FaceRecognition.OpenCV" ?

Comment: What is the problem with adding nuget to `ComputerVision.Core`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a project as a reference of another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397568/how-to-add-a-project-as-a-reference-of-another-project)

Comment: [Manage references in a project (MS Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a project reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019

To test; create a new solution with two projects within it.
Within one project, add a nuget package. Say, Newtonsoft.Json
Add a project reference from your second project to the first

Dependencies should now look like so;
[image: dependencies]

Now within TestConsoleApp, you can add using statements to access the nuget package used in TestConsoleApp2.

eg;

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ExampleObject() { field = "value" });
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }

    public class ExampleObject
    {
        public string field;
    }

}
```

When run outputs {"field":"value"}