# Are there any 3rd-party libraries for XModem in .Net that could help update firmware?

Tags: c#, serial-port, console-application, firmware

I recently developing a `.Net Console app` that could communicate with sas Expander card.

Here comes a problem.

I want to use my console app to update firmware in card.

I have already known It could be update via `Xmodem` protocol

and It could be successful by using `ExtraPuTTy`.

After sending  `fwdl` command in `ExtraPuTTy`:

[image]

After sending `y` command in `ExtraPuTTy`:

[image]

Choose `File Transfer` and `send`

[image]

After transfer, card will restart and give a response `bp1>`

[image]

The SAS card was connected to `RS232` port.

The firmware file's extension is `.FW`.

What I try in my `.Net` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;




namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
           
            
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            string com = "";
            Console.WriteLine("The following serial ports were found:");
            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(port);
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose which port name you want ?");
                com = Console.ReadLine();

            }
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort(com);

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 500000;
            mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 1500;
            mySerialPort.NewLine = "\r";
            mySerialPort.Open();

            if (mySerialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                mySerialPort.Write("\r");
            }

            List<string> Commands = new List<string>();
            string command = "";
            int counter = 0;
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo consoleInput = Console.ReadKey();

                if (consoleInput.KeyChar == '\r')
                {
                    Commands.Add(command);
                    counter = Commands.Count - 1;
                    mySerialPort.Write(command + "\r");
                    if (command == "fwdl")
                    {
                        ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                    }
                    if (command == "y")
                        {
                            String FileName = "";
                            OpenFileDialog openfile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                            if (openfile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                            {
                                FileName = openfile1.FileName;
                            }
                        }
                    
                    ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                    command = "";
                }
                else if (consoleInput.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                {
                    if ((counter >= 0) && (counter < Commands.Count))
                    {
                        ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                        Console.Write(Commands[counter]);
                        foreach (string obj in Commands)
                        {
                            command = obj;
                        }
                        if (consoleInput.KeyChar == '\r')
                        {
                            Commands.Add(command);
                            counter = Commands.Count - 1;
                            mySerialPort.Write(command + "\r");
                            ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                            command = "";
                        }
                    }

                    if (counter > 0)
                    {
                        counter--;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        counter = Commands.Count - 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    command += consoleInput.KeyChar.ToString();
                }
              
            }          
        }
        private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();      // it might be better to use --> string indata = sp.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(indata);
        }

        private static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine()
        {
            int currentLineCursor = Console.CursorTop;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(6, Console.CursorTop);
            Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(6, currentLineCursor);
        }
     
    }

}
```

I only find firmware file and store firmware file's name in variable.

I try to search `XModem c#` in Github.

What I found is https://github.com/yang-chanhong/XModem.

I am not sure that code could use in my console app.

Are there any 3rd-party libraries for XModem in .Net that could help update firmware?

My console app is using `.Net Framework 4.7.2`.

..........................................................

Update 1:

After I add `app1.config` file in my app

[image]

and copy the configuration in the [XmodeProtocol](https://github.com/emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol),

I typed `using XModemProtocol;` in `Program.cs`.

[image]

The error showed up:

[image]

Looks like [XmodeProtocol](https://github.com/emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol)
's configuration isn't clear enough to realize.

Is there something I missed from the [XmodeProtocol](https://github.com/emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol) 's `README.md`?

......................................................

Update 2:

I downloaded the source code on [XmodeProtocol](https://github.com/emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol)

and click `add reference`.

[image]

Choose `Project` Selection and press `Browse` Button.

[image]

I didn't see the Component Files.

What should I do next to add project as reference?

Comment: This repository may be helpful. [emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol](https://github.com/emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol)

Comment: @kunif I updated the question. The config file won't work on app. The error show CS0246 can't find namespace ``using XModemProtocol;``

Comment: It seems that you can add the DLL or Project of XModemProtocol in [Add References of Solution Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019).  [How to: Add or remove references by using the Reference Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019)

Comment: By the way, when I downloaded the XModemProtocol from GitHub and opened the solution on VSC2019, a similar phenomenon occurred in the source of the XModemProtocolTester project. However, although it appears in IntelliSense and the error list pane on the editor, the build completes successfully. Therefore, as a trial, updating the NUnit package to the latest version with NuGet package management solved the display of IntelliSense and the error list pane. I hope it helps.

Comment: @kunif I updated the question. I still can't add project as reference. I really don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please update the NUnit package with the solution of the downloaded repository, and then rebuild by selecting the build menu, batch build, and all projects. Then switch to your project and try adding "XmodemProtocol\bin\Release\XModemProtocol.dll" or "XmodemProtocol\XmodemProtocol.csproj" in AddReferences in Solution Explorer.

Comment: @kunif Thanks. I solved it. I studied this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397568/how-to-add-a-project-as-a-reference-of-another-project to add file as reference.