# How to add references in dot net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, reference

I have a simple project mentioned below.
Can somebody tell me how can I reference my classLibrary1 in classLibrary2, I right-clicked and tried adding reference but that isn't working since I am not able to use the method of classLibrary2 in classLibrary1 (I am inheriting the class of classLibrary1 in classLibrary2 as well)

Why am I not able to see the References folder in classLibrary1 and classLibrary2?

[projectscreen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMhSL.jpg)

PLease help

Comment: You say it's not working, but you haven't said how it's not working. What error do you get? Please be specific.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a project as a reference of another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397568/how-to-add-a-project-as-a-reference-of-another-project)

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Comment: It's resolved now.
Sorry I couldn't reply earlier

Comment: @MintMoney, would you spare a few minutes to post the solution that resolved your question, or accept an existing answer that solved it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't see the reference file is because you created a Class Library.
[image]
[image]

As we can see, the Class Library (.Net Framework) has a References file, but the Class Library does not.

You can right-click on the project and choose Add->Reference to add a reference include the projects in the solution explorer.
[image]
[image]