# How to import 3rd party GitHub libraries into project for C#

Tags: c#, github, shared-libraries, xmodem

I want to use this library in my local project

https://github.com/emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol

I want to use the functions in this library.
There's no instruction how to import it...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would either clone the git repo locally or download the source code from a release: https://github.com/emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol/releases/tag/4.2.0.0, and reference the project directly in your own C# project from the local drive.

Alternative use a nuget package from a different author: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=XModem

Comment: Thank you for your help. I downloaded the release. Now how can I give reference from my C# project?

Comment: assuming you are using Visual Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397568/how-to-add-a-project-as-a-reference-of-another-project

Comment: Thanks a lot, I added the downloaded project as reference