# Include (namespace) file outside of project folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There's a following directory structure:

```
inetpub:

 - Cms
   - Board
   - Core
   - Data
      - ViewModels
        - UserView.cs
   - Design
   - Linkage
   - CMSContent
   - MJBank
   - OuterDLL
   ...
   - Web
     - Cms.Admin
       - Controllers

     - Cms.Web
       - Controllers
       ...
 - wwwroot
```

For example, inside the file `\inetpub\Cms\Web\Cms.Admin\Controllers\UserController.cs` I've got a top statement:

```
using Cms.Data.ViewModels;

...

public string start()
{
      UserView uv = new UserView(); // Error: The type or namespace can not be found
}

...
```

i.e I want to include a file that is located outside of the project folder and it throws an error that it can't find such class.

Is there a way to instruct Visual Studio to find files outside of project folder?

Comment: Probably you have to give _much_ more context. Could bei WebForms (either web application or website), could be MVC, could be MVC Core, could be Razor Pages Core.

Comment: @UweKeim MVC Web Application - .NET Framework 4, ASP.NET 4.8

Comment: Usually you don't have cs files in inetpub. Instead have the *project* elsewhere, compile and publish to a website folder

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Under the `Web` directory, there are 3 web-sites. All of them use shared files outside of their folders (see above), for instance from `Board`  folder. When compiling, Visual Studio throws an error saying that `The type or namespace can not be found` despite being included at the top.

Comment: Very confusing what you actually are doing - on one hand you said "I want to include a file that is located outside of the project folder" on other hand you show unrelated `using Cms.Data.ViewModels;` as part of some code... Can you please clarify if your goal is to add file to a project? (you may need to clarify if it is SDK-style project or old one)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The goal is to include the file (i.e class UserView.) located at `inetpub\Data\ViewModels\UserView.cs` inside the file `\inetpub\Cms\Web\Cms.Admin\Controllers\UserController.cs`. It's SDK. The `.sln` file is located at inetpub\Cms\Web\Cms.Admin\ .Therefore Visual Studio kind of "detects" what's inside the `\inetpub\Cms\Web\Cms.Admin\` folder only.

Comment: Add -> Existing Item -> add as link (alternative to "add"). (That is generally bad idea and having separate assembly built of shared files likely is better, but it will do exactly what you want)

Comment: It sounds like you aren't properly using a Class Library to share the code. The types that you want to reuse across projects should be contained in a Class Library, and then each project should have a reference to the Class Library. Then they can reuse the types in the Class Library.

Comment: Fore more info, see this article on MSDN, which explains how to create a Class Library and use it from another project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Answer (score 1):

From what it seems like you are trying to do, is reference a project.

So, expand the project, where you will be writing your `using namespace` statement.

Right-click references => Add Reference => Projects => 'The project, where the other file is contained'

Now, it should find your namespaces just fine.

Have a look at this : [Add project references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397568/how-to-add-a-project-as-a-reference-of-another-project)